# getting 'the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used' in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to implement this algorithm to numerically compute pi.

```
n2 <- 100
k <- 0
for (k in 1:n2) {
  x2 <- runif(n2, 0.0, 1.0)
  y2 <- runif(n2, 0.0, 1.0)
  if ((x2^2 + y2^2) < 1)
    k <- k+1
    
  return (4*k/n)
}
```

I get the message 'the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used' and i'm not sure where I'm making an error

Comment: `n` id not defined. Don't use `return` function in `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Like was mentioned, `n` isn't defined which is why it will be breaking.

The reason you get the additional warning message:

> "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Is in relation to your `if()` statement, as `(x2^2 + y2^2)` returns a vector of length `100` so only the first element is used in the comparison  `< 1`.

You also don't use `return` statements in `for` loops.